# How can I suspend using a keyboard shortcut, without administrator privileges?

Tags: shortcut-keys, suspend

How can I set up a keyboard shortcut that I can use instead of clicking this menu item?

[image: Suspend]

I have read about various terminal commands for suspending which I could easily assign to a keyboard shortcut, but all have required the use of sudo. I am looking for a solution that I can use on a system where I do not have administer privileges.

Comment: There's a built in shortcut `alt+shift+s`. Validated on 22.04.3 but I think it exists for a very long time now.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

For Ubuntu 15.04. and later you can use from the terminal

```
systemctl suspend
```

Then create a shortcut in the settings/keyboard app with the same command.

[image: key-sortcut]

Easy!

Reason: Ubuntu switched from `upstart` to `systemd`.

Comment: Tested under 16.04

Comment: In 17.10, it's Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard.

Comment: It might be better to use `Super + s` as shortcut instead of `Ctrl + S` which is often used for saving the currently opened document.

Comment: Still working on 18.04

Comment: Still working on `20.04`.

Comment: Still working on 21.04

Comment: Still working on `22.04`

Answer (score 31):

1. Install the [powermanagement-interface](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/powermanagement-interface)  package first, it provides the `pmi` command we will use to suspend.
   **UPDATE**: I looked at the source for `pmi` and the command it uses to suspend is:

   ```
   dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
   ```

   If you can't install `pmi`, replace `pmi action suspend` with that command in the next step.
2. Open up *System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts*, click on *Add* and put `pmi action suspend` as the command.

   [image]
3. Click on the newly created shortcut entry, and set the shortcut keys.

   [image]

Comment: On Precise I had to `apt-get install hal` but working nicely now.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 14.04

Comment: found the answer on this question, using the full command for suspend as the shortcut action, on Ubuntu 15.10 http://askubuntu.com/questions/454039/what-command-is-executed-when-shutdown-from-the-graphical-menu-in-14-04

Comment: Suspend command that worked for me on 16.04 LTS was `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true`

Comment: @MaxGoodridge awesome! Oddly enough `.Hibernate` instead of suspend requires root...

Answer (score 9):

Same as above, but use this command instead:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true
```

Source: http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=16497311#p16497311

Comment: This really should be an edit.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me on 19.10

Comment: Works for me on `20.04`.

Answer (score 4):

`systemctl suspend -i` worked for me.

Mapped to `super+d` in the Keyboard settings custom shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu 16.04 LTS an newer I would suggest using `systemctl` instead because newer systems use `systemd` to control things.

The safe command to run is `systemctl suspend` which suspends the machine immediately unless some process is asking the system to stay powered (e.g. video player showing a movie, active CD burner, another logged in user doing anything, etc).

If you want to force suspend immediately and ignore all "inhibitors" simply add `-i` as explained by the output of the above command.

If you want to immediately lock the screensaver and suspend the system in all cases, you can run

```
loginctl lock-session && systemctl suspend -i
```

This is better than using raw `dbus` to send messages because using `loginctl` and `systemctl` avoids hardcoding any info about your screensaver or session manager.

Answer (score 0):

Here a exaple how to create keyboard shortcut to suspend the system by pressing `<Super> + s` keys:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend "['<Super>s']"
```

or create a custom keybinding:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'suspend'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command 'systemctl suspend'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding '<Super>p'
```