# How to define keyboard shortcut to suspend Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04 on a MacBook Pro. I would like to define a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>) that let's me lock the screen (suspend) Xubuntu. I am following [How can I suspend using a keyboard shortcut, without administrator privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22054/how-can-i-suspend-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-without-administrator-privileges)

The problem is the following: When I try to to define a new shortcut with `System -> Settings -> Settings Manager -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts -> Add`, I only see

```
Shortcut: [no area to type in]
Command: ___________ [area to type in]
```

That means I can put in a command, but no shortcut. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, In Xubuntu it is a bit different, first when you hit **Add** It comes up with this screen-

[image]

Which is exactly as you described, First put the command you want in, from the link you were flowing after installing `powermanagement-interface` you put in the command box `pmi action suspend` then hit **OK** The next screen will let you Key in the Shortcut you want to use, Press the key combo you want to use then release-

[image]

If you accidentally hit a wrong button, or want to edit the shortcut, just double click on the shortcut area of the command-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you can use the command from a terminal first. If you can't, then it obviously wont work as a shortcut.

When I try it, I set Ctrl+Alt+S to

```
pmi action suspend
```

When I press it nothing happens. So, try it from the command line.

```
user@host:~$ pmi action suspend

Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
```

Then the computer does not suspend.

Sorry I can't provide a fix for this, I just wanted to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `hal` package to overcome this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install hal
```