# Adding Keyboard Shortcut For Suspend

Tags: shortcut-keys, suspend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I suspend using a keyboard shortcut, without administrator privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22054/how-can-i-suspend-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-without-administrator-privileges)

Is there a way that I can setup the ctrl-alt-L shortcut to be suspend instead of lock? It seems like it would be much more efficient as I'm not really using lock and unlock every few minutes. I unlock when I start, and lock when I'm done, and the few seconds suspend takes isn't really much time at all. I've looked at `Keyboard>Shortcuts>System` but there isn't a suspend option there, or any other place I looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized. Duplicate question, just showed up on google for me.

[Duplicate Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22054/how-can-i-suspend-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-without-administrator-privileges)